# got a pane element instead of window when using pywinauto

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, ui-automation, pywinauto

so i have this code which is supposed to connect to discord app.

```
import pywinauto
import pywinauto.mouse as mouse
import pywinauto.keyboard as keyboard
from pywinauto.application import Application
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter('ignore', category=UserWarning)
app = Application(backend='uia').connect(path=r"C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Discord\app-0.0.307\Discord.exe")
dlg = app.window(title='Discord')
```

I was confused why the code isn't working, turns out i think it's because discord isn't recognized as a window, but it is recognized as a pane as you can see here in my screenshot: [image: screenshot]

Comment: This is wrong assumption. `control_type` is not specified, so the pane should be detectable as top level window. Which list does `app.windows()` return?

Comment: after i used the title_re method to connect, it works.
```app = Application(backend='win32').connect(title_re=".*Discord.*")```
```dlg = app['Discord']```. I don't know why with the connect path method i can't find the control identifiers.

Comment: Ow and while we are at it can i ask for your discord tag and name so i can add you as a friend? Thanks!

Comment: It could be a child process spawned by launcher process. Pretty typical situation. You can compare `app.process` for both cases. My Discord tag is #8992.

Comment: Ah i see. I compared the PID and turns out it was different. Do you have the tag name?

Comment: Discord user name: `Vasily Ryabov#8992`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because pywinauto won't support the automation process if it's not recognized as the window, i.e pane object.

Comment: That's not true.

Answer (score 1):

Compare app.process and check what the app.windows return.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).